# Time is not Synchronizing

Tags: dual-boot, time, systemd-timesyncd

EDIT: The main problem seems to be that the UTC time is offset. If I fix the UTC clock, then the other time zones will be fixed as well. How can I update the UTC or correct it to the right UTC time (I need to subtract 5 hours)? Thanks.

My Ubuntu 22.04 LTS clock is setting itself to the correct UTC time instead of my time zone which is UTC -5:00 (EST).

The first thing I tried was going into settings and toggling the sync time button but to no avail:[image: Image of settings]

I then ran timedatectl in the terminal which gave me this:

```
           Universal time: Thu 2022-12-01 20:36:11 UTC
                 RTC time: Thu 2022-12-01 15:36:11
                Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: yes

Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local time zone.
         This mode cannot be fully supported. It will create various problems
         with time zone changes and daylight saving time adjustments. The RTC
         time is never updated, it relies on external facilities to maintain it.
         If at all possible, use RTC in UTC by calling
         'timedatectl set-local-rtc 0'.
```

From that I discovered that the UTC time is offset +5:00 from the correct UTC time.

Any ideas for how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly, the issue is related to 'dual-boot' as it stated this question. Which time settings are in the second OS ? And, as workaround, may be to turn off "automatic" timezone detection and manually set appropiate one ? sorry if I misunderstand the question ..

Comment: @TomNewton I am currently using manual time which as you say, is indeed a workaround. I am hoping for a solution to fix the problem, but your suggestion is noted. It is a dual-boot with Windows 11 and it is using the default time settings (I haven't changed anything).

Comment: By some means the issue seems to have resolved itself. I'm not sure what caused or solved the problem as I have not changed any settings or run any commands since posting this question. This does seem to be a recurring problem though so further suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To set too a more standard approach try `timedatectl set-local-rtc 0` and `timedatectl set-ntp`
It based on the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html).
this will revert your time set up to a more conventional obtain network time. Synchronise local real time clock to this. Timezones are then applied to this. At present you have priority to local clock and are **double shifting** by the sound of it. you may need to prefix both with `sudo` .

To revert back to your current config change the 0 to 1 in the first command

Comment: When I run the first command I get ```timedatectl: invalid option -- 's'``` back. Same for the second command.

Comment: My bad - a stray "-" crept in infront of set...., edited to correct this